# I have Mysterious C code witch have different behavior at same test case , I think it is coodblock problem

Tags: c

This code should give the max number in array but when I Enter

4 3 2 1 it give me 3 But if I enter 5 4 3 2 it gives me 5

So can any one tell me why there are 2 behaviors for the same case ?

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d){

    int arr[4]= {a,b,c,d};
    int i , j;

    for (i=0 ; i<=3 ;i ++)
    {
        for (j=i+1 ; j<=3 ; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i]>arr[j])
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
               break;
        }
        if (arr[i]>arr[j])
        {
            return arr[i];
        }
    }
    return arr[j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your inner loop, if the element at index `i` is the largest value then the inner loop goes through all values of `j` from 0 to 3, and `j` will be 4 when the loop exits.  When you then check `arr[i]>arr[j]`, you're reading past the end of the array when `j` is 4.  Reading past the end of an array invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which is why you see inconsistent results.

Instead, check if `j` is 4.  If it is, you know you `arr[i]` is the largest.

```
    for (j=i+1 ; j<=3 ; j++)
    {
        if (arr[i]>arr[j])
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
           break;
    }
    if (j == 4)
    {
        return arr[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the max value in an array you only need to iterate over the array once.

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int[] arr= {a,b,c,d};
    int i = 0;

    // set max as the first element in the array
    int max = arr[0];     // arr[0]

    // loop index from 1 to 3
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        // if element is greater than current max
        if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
    }

    return max;
}

// output
// max_of_four(4,3,2,1):
// 4

// max_of_four(1,5,4,2):
// 5
```